# How To upload data from textbox with image in indexed db

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have been trying for past two days . I have two textbox with a file upload and everything is working and storing in the db but the image is not. Textbox data is storing in the indexed db but the image is not storing in the indexed db it is showing as empty array for the `image[]` . this is my javascript add function

```
function add() {
  var a = document.getElementById("userfile");
  var b = a.files[0];

  var request = db.transaction(["todostore"], "readwrite")
  .objectStore("todostore")
  .add({
    timestamp: "KP" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    todo: $("#todo").val(),
    price:$("#toprice").val(),
    image:b
  });

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    alert($("#todo").val() + " has been added to your database.");
    $("#todo").val("");
  };
};
```

and this is the code of the html. I am not been able to identify the error.

```
<label for="todo">To Do:</label>
<input id="todo" type="text">
<input id="toprice" type="text">
<input type="file" id="userfile" />

<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586006/store-an-image-file-in-indexeddb

Comment: @joaumg can you tell me whats wrong with this function

Comment: any help plz? i am trying for many hours

Comment: didn't notice anything wrong with it. This works: https://jsfiddle.net/mozb7z0q/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Blob directly to the IndexedDB is a mystery to me, however.

We can add the image as a base64 using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) as follow:

```
function add() {
  var files = document.getElementById("userfile").files
  if (!files || !files.length) return

  var fileReader = new FileReader()
  fileReader.onload = function () {
    var request = db.transaction(["todostore"], "readwrite")
      .objectStore("todostore")
      .add({
        timestamp: "KP" + Date.now(),
        todo: $("#todo").val(),
        price: $("#toprice").val(),
        image: reader.result // changing here
      })
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      alert($("#todo").val() + " has been added to your database.")
      $("#todo").val("")
    }
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])
}
```

Comment: not working todoapp.html:102 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)

Comment: Could you recheck? @Endless did edit it, but I'd rolled back because of inconsistency, now I've saw your comment ;\